# Can all Windows Store apps run on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-rt

I can't find a clear answer on this question. I'm working on a study for a client who has Windows 8 Pro devices and needs a specific application. We've found which is flagged as a "Windows RT" app. How do I know if it can run on Windows 8 Pro ?

Comment: Store apps are distributed through the Store.  So just download it.  If it is exclusively for WindowsRT tablets then you can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows store apps know what platforms they run on.  Windows RT is the OS made to run on ARM processors, while x86 and x64 are your normal desktop and laptop computers.  The app developer chooses which platforms are supported so its possible the app only works on ARM although I'd be a bit surprised.

Comment: OK, I have the answer: a WindowsStore app can be specific for RT, but the main case is that WS apps are compatible with both. I just have to  check on the WS to check if it is available for one or both. The thing is that I don't have a W8 pro system I could test with... Thanks.

Comment: You can see the apps online.  Here's the WS facebook app.  On the right it tells you which platforms it runs on:  http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/facebook/ADD3D66A-358D-4FE2-BE68-8A3F934E9EA1?ocid=Apps_O_WOL_FavTile_App_FA_Facebook_Pos3

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to see an app in your systems app store that it means the system fulfills required criteria for the app. So the app will be install-able.